# How to disable right click (add watermark) and fade content?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

How to add Disable right click (add watermark) and Fade content when changing gallery items in one script.

My code that does not work:

```
$(".fancybox")
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
.fancybox({
    nextMethod : 'resizeIn',
    nextSpeed  : 250,

    prevMethod : false,

    helpers : {
        title : {
            type : 'inside'
        }
    }
 });

$(".fancybox")
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
.fancybox({
    beforeShow: function () {
        /* Disable right click */
        $.fancybox.wrap.bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
                return false; 
        });
    }
 });
```

Comment: Not to venture off-topic here but consider if you really need to disable right-clicking. As a user it is one of my biggest pet peeves and it doesn't prevent anyone from actually downloading any images (You can screenshot, you can go into the source and rip it out, etc.) It's just a big inconvenience because it makes everything else found in the right-click menu harder to access as well.

Answer (score 1):

Put all the API options you want in a single script init (just separate them with commas but the last)

```
$(".fancybox")
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
.fancybox({
    nextMethod : 'resizeIn',
    nextSpeed  : 250,
    prevMethod : false,
    helpers : {
        title : {
            type : 'inside'
        }
    },
    beforeShow: function () {
        /* Disable right click */
        $.fancybox.wrap.bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
                return false; 
        });
    }
    // ,
    // some other options or callbacks go here
 });
```